# Facebook Like and Share Buttons with Separate Counts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I use the the code generated at [Facebook Developer Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) which displays the **sum** of likes and shares.

```
 <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&amp;width&amp;layout=box_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=65&amp;appId=131242507044074" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:65px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I want to display 2 separate boxes with like and share counts. It is possible to get them using [FQL](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20url,like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20=%20%22https://stackoverflow.com/%22) but I don't want to deal with parsing it. Does Facebook offer an easier way to display them separately?

Answer (score 1):

Great News! Facebook updated their code *some-amount-of-time* ago!
Now you can load the Share button separately from the Like button and have individual counts as well, and still use the same invocation code. When I first created my personal social media plugin I could only load both Like and Share or just Like and the count was only for the Like button. Just updated everything. :)

The links in @Fabio's post took me to an updated page with the new code for the buttons. The Share one is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Gotta say, as much as their updates frustrate me sometimes, I like how FB is staying up to date and fixing issues as we complain about them.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your url's share and like counts separately and you can further get total counts and comments counts as well by using FQL below

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.bing.com'
```